# Masonry. Как правильно использовать?

Tags: javascript, html

Не получается воспользоваться manosry сеткой.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Что я делаю не так? И как правильно его использовать?

```js
var answers = [{
  "answer_name": "Тирион Ланнистер",
  "strong": "Взаимосвязь с природой на уровне Земли, взаимодействие с Землей, с животными, с растениями, непосредственно с самим планом Земли, дает ту жизненную энергию, которая позволяет физическому телу развиваться.",
}, {
  "answer_name": "Джейме Ланнистер",
  "strong": "Старший сын Эддарда Робб Старк, провозглашённый Королем Севера, продолжает войну с Тайвином Ланнистером, а сын самого Тайвина, карлик Тирион, на короткое время оказывается де-факто во главе государства в качестве «десницы». Станнис, с помощью чёрной магии убив Ренли и завладев его армией, пытается захватить столицу Семи Королевств, но благодаря хитрости Тириона и союзу Ланнистеров с могущественным домом Тиреллов терпит поражение в битве при Черноводной.",
}, {
  "answer_name": "Арья Старк",
  "strong": "На службе у Станниса находятся бывший контрабандист Давос Сиворт (Лиам Каннингем) и красная жрица Мелисандра (Кэрис ван Хаутен), проповедующая веру во Владыку Света. Лорд Штормовых Земель Ренли, самый младший из братьев Роберта, тоже пытается занять Железный трон. Он женится на представительнице дома Тиреллов",
}, ];

function createStrongs(strongs) {
  var strongsTo = document.getElementById("strongs");

  strongsTo.innerHTML = strongs.map(function(answer) {
    return '<div class="answer thumbnail grid-item ">\
                    <h5 class="answer-name">' + answer.answer_name + '</h5>\
                    <p class="answer-text">' + answer.strong + '</p>\
            </div>'
  }).join('');
}

createStrongs(answers);
```

```html
<div class="row answers grid js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 200 }' id="strongs">

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: а там случаем библиотеку jquery не нужно загружать?

Comment: сниппет выводит ошибку: _Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery_

Comment: @NeedHate Ой, забыла. Но у меня jQuery подключен, а дела это не меняет. :(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, первое что надо сделать - задать ширину для *grid-item*

Например:

```
.grid-item{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```js
var answers = [{
  "answer_name": "Тирион Ланнистер",
  "strong": "Взаимосвязь с природой на уровне Земли, взаимодействие с Землей, с животными, с растениями, непосредственно с самим планом Земли, дает ту жизненную энергию, которая позволяет физическому телу развиваться.",
}, {
  "answer_name": "Джейме Ланнистер",
  "strong": "Старший сын Эддарда Робб Старк, провозглашённый Королем Севера, продолжает войну с Тайвином Ланнистером, а сын самого Тайвина, карлик Тирион, на короткое время оказывается де-факто во главе государства в качестве «десницы». Станнис, с помощью чёрной магии убив Ренли и завладев его армией, пытается захватить столицу Семи Королевств, но благодаря хитрости Тириона и союзу Ланнистеров с могущественным домом Тиреллов терпит поражение в битве при Черноводной.",
}, {
  "answer_name": "Арья Старк",
  "strong": "На службе у Станниса находятся бывший контрабандист Давос Сиворт (Лиам Каннингем) и красная жрица Мелисандра (Кэрис ван Хаутен), проповедующая веру во Владыку Света. Лорд Штормовых Земель Ренли, самый младший из братьев Роберта, тоже пытается занять Железный трон. Он женится на представительнице дома Тиреллов",
}, ];

function createStrongs(strongs) {
  var strongsTo = document.getElementById("strongs");

  strongsTo.innerHTML = strongs.map(function(answer) {
    return '<div class="answer thumbnail grid-item ">\
                    <h5 class="answer-name">' + answer.answer_name + '</h5>\
                    <p class="answer-text">' + answer.strong + '</p>\
            </div>'
  }).join('');
}

createStrongs(answers);
```

```css
.grid-item{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row answers grid js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 200 }' id="strongs">

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: чувствую сейчас себя жутким тормозом )))) спасибо